# How to fix Connection string is not valid using multiple server name

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have problem regarding implementing multiple server name they told me to put the server name to the array so i workout on it and i make the array look like this. `$serverNames = ["xx.xx.xx.xxx\\sqlexpress", "xx.xx.xx.xxx\\sqlexpress"];` then i put it on the implode. `$List = implode(', ', $serverName);` however the arraying the servernames is not working. it gives me error.

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 87 [code] => 87 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 87 [code] => 87 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. ) )

To see more my codes that I already created, i will show you my sample.

```
<?php 



        $serverNames = ["xx.xx.xx.xxx\\sqlexpress", "xx.xx.xx.xxx\\sqlexpress"];//serverName\instanceName

        foreach($serverNames as $ip) {

            $ip_array = $ip;

            $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"users", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"1234");
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $ip_array, $connectionInfo);

            if( $conn ) {       
            }else{
                 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
                 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }
        }

        $tsql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql);

        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td style="font-size:11px;">'.$row['Firstname'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td style="font-size:11px;">'.$row['LastName'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td style="font-size:11px;">'.$row['DateBirth'].'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';


        }


    ?>
```

Comment: change `die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));` to `echo( "<pre>$ip errors: " . print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) . "</pre>" );` and see if the second one connects.

Comment: @WEBjuju sure i will

Comment: @SoulAiker, i think you don't need to escape backlash if using double quotes. `xx.xx.xx.xxx\sqlexpress`

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ  the only data that i get is the second value of the array. the first ip is not joining.

Comment: @WEBjuju the only data that i get is the second value of the array. the first ip is not joining.

Comment: I don't know why one of them works and other doesn't, but I'm going to offer a solution in an answer...you only need one connection...I would guess.

Comment: what do you mean @WEBjuju ? only need one connection can you explain more?

Comment: well, actually, you have to explain why you need more than one.

Comment: why? because the data from other server is different from the first server.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to each server, pull the data rows from that server, or print an error message row if that server is unavailable.

```
<?php
$serverNames = ['xx.xx.xx.xxx\\sqlexpress', 'xx.xx.xx.xxx\\sqlexpress'];
$connectionInfo = array('Database'=>'users', 'UID'=>'sa', 'PWD'=>'1234');

foreach ($serverNames as $ip) {
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect($ip, $connectionInfo);

  if (empty($conn)) {

    //  data of one server is not extracting to the table
    echo '<tr><td colspan="3">Connection to <strong>Server ';
    echo $ip;
    echo '</strong> could not be established.</td></tr>';
  } else {

    $tsql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td style="font-size:11px;">'.$row['Firstname'].'</td>';
      echo '<td style="font-size:11px;">'.$row['LastName'].'</td>';
      echo '<td style="font-size:11px;">'.$row['DateBirth'].'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: breaking the one connection getting only 1 ip address, i want the data of both ip address

Comment: I see. and what should happen if one of them can't connect?

Comment: if that so, the data of one server is not extracting to the table.

Comment: I updated the code to pick up the rows of users from each server, I have the error creating a row in the table...you can remove that as desired.